# Is there a plainer english explanation of bravery and poltroonery?

Tags: en-garde

Despite having reread the rules section multiple times, I don't understand how death numbers, death rolls and bravery / poltroonery settings other than flat numerical modifiers work.  Is there an idiots guide?  How do they work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Limited Bravery and how you get to modify your death rolls.

You place in your orders Bravery: 8 (we're going to be silly brave)

Scenario 1: The death number set by the GM is equal to or lower than 8.

What happens: Nothing, he rolls 2d6 and if that number is equal to or higher than the set death number, you die. If it is less, your character lives and then rolls are made for loot, MiD, etc.

Scenario 2: The death number is Higher than 8.

What happens: The GM takes the death number minus your bravery number, then adds that to his death roll. So if the death number was 10.  He would take 10-8= 2 and add 2 to his death roll. He would then roll 2d6+2 and if that number was equal to or higher than 10, your character would die. If it was lower, then your character would live. AND get a +2 to all his loot, MiD, etc.

For Completion

Poltroonery goes to 11 (yes, I'll make that pun)

Scenario 1: The Death number set by GM is 11 or higher

What happens: Nothing, rolls 2d6 if number is equal to or greater than, you die. Same as scenario 1 on the bravery side.

Scenario 2: Death number is 10 or lower.

What happens: GM takes your Poltroonery number minus the death number, then subtracts that number from the death roll. So if the death number was 2. you take 11-2=9. Then roll 2d6-9 and if that number was equal to/greater than 2 you then die. If it was lower your character would still be alive, but you would probably be called a coward for running away.Disgraced, kicked out of your unit, etc etc.

Comment: This helps incredibly!  I was unable to parse the rules as written, whereas this makes sense!

Comment: Just to be sure: this means that the lower the death number is, the more likely you are to die, right?

Comment: @Scrollmaster The more reckless bravery there is than necessary, the more likely the fool is going to go and *make* the situation dangerous enough to get killed, is how I understand it. Of course, fortune favours the bold, so if you win the gamble and don't get yourself killed you get the rewards of going so far above and beyond.

Comment: Correct, To be more D&D non-thac0  the Death number is your AC and the death roll is his attack against your AC.